I have a problem [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'signed_values')]
i need help around the create signed value and create signed data (i think that it needs to be async to wait for the signed data values to be created but i don't know exactly how to get around this) is there anyway to make it so that i can use the createsignedvalue before the createsigneddata?
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Cdr } from './entities/cdr.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { CdrLocation } from 'src/common/entities/cdr-location.entity';
import { CdrToken } from 'src/common/entities/cdr-token.entity';
import { ChargingPeriod } from 'src/common/entities/charging-period.entity';
import { CdrDimension } from 'src/common/entities/cdr-dimension.entity';
import { SignedData } from 'src/common/entities/signed-data.entity';
import { Price } from 'src/common/entities/price.entity';
import { CreateCdrDto } from './dtos/create-cdr.dto';
import { cdrLocationDto } from './dtos/create-cdr-location.dto';
import { GeoLocation } from 'src/common/entities/geo-location.entity';
import { cdrTokenDto } from './dtos/create-cdr-token.dto';
import { SignedValue } from 'src/common/entities/signed-value.entity';
import { Tariff } from 'src/tariff/entities/tariff.entity';

@Injectable()
export class CdrService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Cdr)
    private cdrRepository: Repository<Cdr>,
    @InjectRepository(CdrLocation)
    private cdrLocationRepository: Repository<CdrLocation>,
    @InjectRepository(CdrToken)
    private cdrTokenRepository: Repository<CdrToken>,
    @InjectRepository(ChargingPeriod)
    private chargingPeriodRepository: Repository<ChargingPeriod>,
    @InjectRepository(CdrDimension)
    private cdrDimensionRepository: Repository<CdrDimension>,
    @InjectRepository(SignedData)
    private signedDataRepository: Repository<SignedData>,
    @InjectRepository(Price)
    private priceRepository: Repository<Price>,
    @InjectRepository(GeoLocation)
    private geoLocationRepository: Repository<GeoLocation>,
    @InjectRepository(SignedValue)
    private signedValueRepository: Repository<SignedValue>,
    @InjectRepository(Tariff)
    private tariffRepository: Repository<Tariff>,
  ) {}

  async createCdr(createCdrDto: CreateCdrDto): Promise<Cdr> {
    const {
      cdr_location,
      cdr_token,
      charging_periods,
      signed_data,
      tariffs,
      ...cdrData
    } = createCdrDto;
    let coordinates = await this.geoLocationRepository.findOne({
      where: {
        lat: cdr_location[0].coordinates.latitude,
        lng: cdr_location[0].coordinates.longitude,
      },
    });
    let createCdrLocation = this.cdrLocationRepository.create({
      name: cdr_location[0].name,
      address: cdr_location[0].address,
      city: cdr_location[0].city,
      postal_code: cdr_location[0].postal_code,
      country: cdr_location[0].country,
      coordinates: coordinates,
      state: cdr_location[0].state,
      evse_uid: cdr_location[0].evse_uid,
      evse_id: cdr_location[0].evse_id,
      connector_id: cdr_location[0].connector_id,
      connector_standard: cdr_location[0].connector_standard,
      connector_format: cdr_location[0].connector_format,
      connector_power_type: cdr_location[0].connector_power_type,
    });
    let createCdrToken = this.cdrTokenRepository.create({
      country_code: cdr_token[0].country_code,
      party_id: cdr_token[0].party_id,
      type: cdr_token[0].type,
      contract_id: cdr_token[0].contract_id,
    });

    let createSignedValue = await this.signedValueRepository.create({
      nature: signed_data[0].signed_values[0].nature,
      plain_data: signed_data[0].signed_values[0].plain_data,
      signed_data: signed_data[0].signed_values[0].signed_data,
    });

    let createSignedData = this.signedDataRepository.create({
      encoding_method: signed_data[0].encoding_method,
      encoding_method_version: signed_data[0].encoding_method_version,
      public_key: signed_data[0].public_key,
      url: signed_data[0].url,
      signed_values: [createSignedValue],
    });
    let tariff = await this.tariffRepository.findOne({
      where: {
        tariff_alt_url: tariffs[0].tariff_alt_url,
      },
    });
    let createCdrDimension = this.cdrDimensionRepository.create({
      type: charging_periods[0].dimensions[0].type,
      volume: charging_periods[0].dimensions[0].volume,
    });
    let createChargingPeriod = this.chargingPeriodRepository.create({
      start_date_time: charging_periods[0].start_date_time,
      dimensions: [createCdrDimension],
      tariff_id: charging_periods[0].tariff_id,
    });
    let createCdr = this.cdrRepository.create({
      ...cdrData,
      cdr_location: [createCdrLocation],
      cdr_token: [createCdrToken],
      charging_periods: [createChargingPeriod],
      signed_data: createSignedData,
      tariffs: [tariff],
    });
    return await this.cdrRepository.save(createCdr);
  }
}


To be able to add a json request to postgres Database but i get that error when i post
